# Inequalities of trace of inverse matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

From the Taylor series of $\frac{1}{1-x}$, we have
$$\frac{1}{1-x} - 1-x \ge C x^2$$
provided $x \in [0,1)$.

Do we have a similar inequality for the $d \times d$ matrix $A$? For example, does
$$Tr((I-A)^{-1}) - d - Tr(A) \ge C \cdot Tr(A)^2$$
hold for positive definite $A$?

Comment: So the trace of the inverse matrix is just $\lambda_1^{-1}+\lambda_2^{-1}+\dots+\lambda_d^{-1}$, where $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\dots,\lambda_d$ are the eigenvalues of $A$. So if you wanted a similar inequality for positive definite matrices, it's equivalent to proving, for $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n>0$, that $\sum_{i=1}^d(1-\lambda_i)^{-1}-d-\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i\ge C\cdot(\sum_{i=1}^d\lambda_i)^2$. I'll see what I can do with this, but hopefully this will guide you on the right direction.

Comment: Actually, just by summing $(1-\lambda_i)^{-1}-1-\lambda_i\ge C\cdot\lambda_i^2$, we can get $\text{tr}((I-A)^{-1})-d-\text{tr}(A)\ge C\cdot\text{tr}(A^2)$. I also think the largest $C$ that this always works is $C=1$, because you can take $A=\epsilon I$ for $\epsilon\to0^+$.

Answer (score 1):

No. Try this: $$A=\begin{bmatrix}
2 & -1 & 0\\ 
-1 & 2 & -1\\ 
0 & -1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}$$